# Wrong docker image on Github Actions

Tags: docker, github-actions

I'm building CI/CD on Github Actions, and I want to use a specific docker image.

I used this yaml file:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    name: Test Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: lambci/lambda:build-nodejs12.x
    steps:
      - name: What OS is running
        run: uname -a
```

But I'm getting the wrong image:

```
Linux b25c9fe8c287 5.4.0-1031-azure #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 6 10:03:22 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

instead of

```
Linux 758d8f59b7b6 5.4.39-linuxkit #1 SMP Fri May 8 23:03:06 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you know you should get this image? `Linux b25c9fe8c287 5.4.0-1031-azure #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 6 10:03:22 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `uname -a` shows you what kernel is running. There are no kernels shipped with docker images, instead you get the Linux kernel of the host. Docker is a method to run isolated processes, not a virtual machine environment, and therefore you should expect the output of `uname -a` to vary depending on where you run the image.